# How to run sudo rosrun

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosrun, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I launch rosrun and roslaunch commands with sudo? Why It is not possible by default? Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194247/how-to-run-sudo-rosrun/) by [vd77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20364/vd77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its not possible because sudo is calling the command as root; and your enviroment variables (source setup.bash) are not set for user root!

Theoretically you could log in as root (`sudo su`) then source and setup everything and then run your nodes as root; However, I'd highly recommend not to do that and find a way to run your nodes as normal user...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-28**:
Thanq.. I was searching for this only